# Does MySQL different engine types (InnoDB and Aria) affect on query with large amount of LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, left-join, innodb, explain

I have one heavy MySQL query with 12 `LEFT JOIN` and noticed that some of tables have `InnoDB` engine and some `Aria`.
I've attached `EXPLAIN` of this query and pointed engine types at image with corresponding letters `I` and `A`.

Does fact of different engines affects on query speed and how seriously? Does changing of engines types helps to optimize query execution?

What else I could do to optimize this query?

[image]

Query (if needed)

```
SELECT user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name, user.birthday, user.email, user.phone, user.address_id, 
        user.alt_address_id, user.type, user.level_id, user_level.level, user.consecutive_orders, user.orders_count, 
        user.code_id, user.period, user.preferences, user.is_pick_up, user.pickup_address_id, user.is_active, 
        user.first_delivery_date, user.change_delivery_date, user.eway_id, user.date_created, 
        user.rest_referral_discount as `rest_referral_discount`, user.rest_code_discount as `rest_code_discount`, 
        user.rest_code_box_discount as `rest_code_box_discount`, user.rest_code_mp_discount as `rest_code_mp_discount`, 
        user.rest_code_tup_discount as `rest_code_tup_discount`, user.nf_pantry_list, user.nf_next_weeks_menu, 
        user.nf_paused_reminder, user.nf_welcome, user.nf_expected_delivery_time, 
        user.nf_delivery, address_pickup.address as `pickup_address`, address.address, address.unit, 
        address.instructions, location.id location_id, location.postcode, location.suburb, 
        location_state.code state_code, delivery_area.delivery_area_window_id delivery_area_window_id, 
        delivery_area_by_location.fee delivery_fee_value, delivery_area_window.day delivery_day, 
        delivery_area_window.day_name_full delivery_day_name_full, delivery_area_window.window delivery_window, 
        user.delivery_area_id, user.alt_delivery_area_id, if (user.is_pick_up, 0, delivery_area.fee) delivery_fee, 
        if (user.type = 1 || user.type = 2, 5, 0) ondemand_fee, code.code code_name, code.amount code_amount, 
        code.value code_value, code.is_permanent is_code_permanent, code.repeat code_repeat, code.times code_times, 
        code.apply_to code_apply_to, code.valid_from code_valid_from, code.valid_until code_valid_until, 
        if (code_used.count > 0, 1, 0) is_code_used, if (code_used.count > 0, code_used.count, 0) code_used_count, 
        if (user.is_pick_up, IFNULL(delivery_area_by_location.topup_available, 0), IFNULL(delivery_area.topup_available, 0)) topup_available,
        
        (SELECT `order`.`id` FROM `order` LEFT JOIN `gift` ON gift.order_id = order.id 
        WHERE (`order`.`delivery_date` BETWEEN '2021-02-07' and '2021-02-13') and (user.id = order.user_id) and (`gift`.`id` IS NULL) 
        and (`order`.`status` = 10) ORDER BY `order`.`date_created` DESC LIMIT 1) as `order_id`,
         
        (SELECT `order`.`delivery_date` FROM `order` 
        LEFT JOIN `gift` 
            ON gift.order_id = order.id 
        WHERE (user.id = order.user_id) and (`gift`.`id` IS NULL) and (`order`.`status` = 10) ORDER BY `order`.`date_created` DESC LIMIT 1) as `last_order_delivery_date` 
        
        FROM `user` 
        
        LEFT JOIN `address` 
            ON user.address_id = address.id 
        LEFT JOIN `address_pickup` 
            ON user.pickup_address_id = address_pickup.id 
        LEFT JOIN `delivery_area` 
            ON user.delivery_area_id = delivery_area.id 
        LEFT JOIN `delivery_area_window` 
            ON delivery_area_window.id = delivery_area.delivery_area_window_id 
        LEFT JOIN `user_level` 
            ON user.level_id = user_level.id 
        LEFT JOIN `location` 
            ON address.location_id = location.id 
        LEFT JOIN `location_state` 
            ON location.state_id = location_state.id 
        LEFT JOIN `delivery_area` `delivery_area_by_location` ON delivery_area_by_location.location_id = location.id 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) count, `user_id`, `code_id` FROM `order` WHERE (code_id > 0) and (`order`.`status` = 10) GROUP BY `user_id`, `code_id`) `code_used` 
            ON ((user.id = code_used.user_id) and (code_used.code_id = user.code_id)) 
        LEFT JOIN `code` 
            ON user.code_id = code.id WHERE (`user`.`type` = 0) and (`user`.`status` = 10) 
            
        GROUP BY `user`.`id` ORDER BY `last_name` LIMIT 15
```

UPD: `CREATE TABLE`

```
    CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `unit` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `instructions` text NOT NULL,
  `regular` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `topup` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_to` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `address_pickup` (
  `id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `code` (
  `id` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - number; 1 - percent',
  `is_mswa` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_permanent` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `repeat` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_to` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - both; 1 - box; 2 -  mp;',
  `times` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `valid_from` date NOT NULL,
  `valid_until` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `checkout_text` text NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `delivery_area` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fee` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `delivery_area_window_id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `topup_available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `delivery_area_window` (
  `id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `day` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `day_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `day_name_full` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `window` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pickup` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `gift` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `recipient_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - card; 1 - box;',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `token` char(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_redeemed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_exp` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `postcode` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `suburb` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `dc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type_id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `lat` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `location_state` (
  `id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `shipping_address_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `topup_address_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pickup_address_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `preferences` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `referral_discount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `code_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code_discount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `pickup_discount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `admin_discount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `level_discount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `delivery_fee` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `topup_delivery_fee` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `ondemand_fee` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `retry_payment` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1-wait answer; 2-recharge with sms; 3-recharge without sms',
  `retry_payment_sms` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - processed; >0 - sms id',
  `retry_payment_email` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `eway_errors` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `processing_status` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `processing_status_edited` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `has_topup` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_topup_only` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password_reset_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_ref_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eway_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'eWAY Customer Token ID',
  `active_campaign_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ActiveCampaign subscriber_id',
  `level_id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `address_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delivery_area_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_address_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_delivery_area_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `period` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 - Once a Week; 2 - Fortnightly',
  `preferences` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_pick_up` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pickup_address_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0 - Inactive; 1 - Active; -1 - Blocked',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
  `type` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - Set And Forget; 1 - On Demand; 2 - Trial; 3 - Potential;',
  `first_delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_delivery_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nf_pantry_list` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `nf_next_weeks_menu` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `nf_paused_reminder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `nf_expected_delivery_time` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `nf_delivery` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `nf_welcome` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `consecutive_orders` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_count` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rest_referral_discount` decimal(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rest_code_discount` decimal(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rest_code_box_discount` decimal(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rest_code_mp_discount` decimal(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rest_code_tup_discount` decimal(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_level` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `discount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And indexes

```
    --
-- Indexes table `address`
--
ALTER TABLE `address`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
  ADD KEY `regular` (`regular`),
  ADD KEY `topup` (`topup`),
  ADD KEY `date_to` (`date_to`),
  ADD KEY `date_from` (`date_from`);

--
-- Indexes table `address_pickup`
--
ALTER TABLE `address_pickup`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes table `code`
--
ALTER TABLE `code`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `valid_from` (`valid_from`),
  ADD KEY `valid_until` (`valid_until`),
  ADD KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  ADD KEY `code` (`code`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `is_mswa` (`is_mswa`);

--
-- Indexes table `delivery_area`
--
ALTER TABLE `delivery_area`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `day` (`delivery_area_window_id`),
  ADD KEY `location_id` (`location_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `friday_topup_available` (`topup_available`);

--
-- Indexes table `delivery_area_window`
--
ALTER TABLE `delivery_area_window`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `day` (`day`),
  ADD KEY `pickup_only` (`pickup`);

--
-- Indexes table `gift`
--
ALTER TABLE `gift`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `token` (`token`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `recipient_id` (`recipient_id`),
  ADD KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  ADD KEY `is_redeemed` (`is_redeemed`);

--
-- Indexes table `location`
--
ALTER TABLE `location`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `idx_lon` (`lon`),
  ADD KEY `idx_lat` (`lat`),
  ADD KEY `type_id` (`type_id`),
  ADD KEY `state_id` (`state_id`),
  ADD KEY `postcode` (`postcode`),
  ADD KEY `suburb_2` (`suburb`),
  ADD KEY `postcode_suburb` (`postcode`,`suburb`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `location` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `suburb` (`suburb`);

--
-- Indexes table `location_state`
--
ALTER TABLE `location_state`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes table `order`
--
ALTER TABLE `order`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `client_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `shipping_address_id` (`shipping_address_id`),
  ADD KEY `preferences` (`preferences`),
  ADD KEY `processing_status` (`processing_status`),
  ADD KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  ADD KEY `delivery_date` (`delivery_date`),
  ADD KEY `pickup_address_id` (`pickup_address_id`),
  ADD KEY `processing_status_edited` (`processing_status_edited`),
  ADD KEY `retry_payment_sms` (`retry_payment_sms`),
  ADD KEY `retry_payment` (`retry_payment`),
  ADD KEY `retry_payment_email` (`retry_payment_email`),
  ADD KEY `has_topup` (`has_topup`),
  ADD KEY `is_topup_only` (`is_topup_only`),
  ADD KEY `friday_address_id` (`topup_address_id`),
  ADD KEY `code_id` (`code_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

--
-- Indexes table `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `password_reset_token` (`password_reset_token`),
  ADD KEY `level_id` (`level_id`),
  ADD KEY `eway_id` (`eway_id`),
  ADD KEY `password_hash` (`password_hash`),
  ADD KEY `auth_key` (`auth_key`),
  ADD KEY `email` (`email`),
  ADD KEY `period` (`period`),
  ADD KEY `preferences` (`preferences`),
  ADD KEY `is_pick_up` (`is_pick_up`),
  ADD KEY `is_active` (`is_active`),
  ADD KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  ADD KEY `phone` (`phone`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `active_campaign_id` (`active_campaign_id`),
  ADD KEY `custom_ref_code` (`custom_ref_code`),
  ADD KEY `consecutive_orders` (`consecutive_orders`),
  ADD KEY `pickup_address_id` (`pickup_address_id`),
  ADD KEY `rest_referral_discount` (`rest_referral_discount`),
  ADD KEY `rest_code_discount` (`rest_code_discount`),
  ADD KEY `rest_code_box_discount` (`rest_code_box_discount`),
  ADD KEY `rest_code_mp_discount` (`rest_code_mp_discount`),
  ADD KEY `delivery_area_id` (`delivery_area_id`),
  ADD KEY `rest_code_tup_discount` (`rest_code_tup_discount`),
  ADD KEY `orders_count` (`orders_count`),
  ADD KEY `alt_delivery_address_id` (`alt_address_id`),
  ADD KEY `alt_delivery_area_id` (`alt_delivery_area_id`),
  ADD KEY `address_id` (`address_id`),
  ADD KEY `code_id` (`code_id`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`),
  ADD KEY `type` (`type`),
  ADD KEY `last_name` (`last_name`);

--
-- Indexes table `user_level`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_level`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT
--
ALTER TABLE `address`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `address_pickup`
  MODIFY `id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `code`
  MODIFY `id` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `delivery_area`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `delivery_area_window`
  MODIFY `id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `gift`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `location`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `location_state`
  MODIFY `id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `order`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `user`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `user_level`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

For table `order`:

```
INDEX(status, code_id, order_id)
INDEX(status, order_id, code_id)
```

(I can't tell which would be better; the Optimizer can decide.)

Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when the 'right' table is not optional.  It makes it tedious for a human (and the Optimizer) to figure the intent.

`User` needs

```
 INDEX(type, status, code_id, code, id, last_name)
```

It is almost always beneficial to DROP INDEX(a) when you ADD INDEX(a,b).  I bring that up because you probably have some one-column indexes.

If you need further help, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I suspect that the query could be turned inside-out to great benefit.  This involves finding the 15 ids *first*; then *after that* do all the `JOINs`.

That might have this as the first "derived" table since it generates *only 15 rows*, not the 9976 estimated in the Explain:

```
FROM ( SELECT  id, `code`, code_id, last_name
        FROM user
        WHERE  `type` = 0
          AND  `status` = 10
        GROUP BY  `id`
        ORDER BY  `last_name`
        LIMIT  15
     ) AS u
JOIN ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Rick. Yes, you are totally right, there are single indexes everywhere. I tried multiple indexes for `user` and `order` tables and explain shows me there is no benefit. `INDEX(status, order_id, code_id)` shows me the same amount of processed rows and the other combination is much more. About user - adding single index 'last_name' for WHERE condition gives me benefit - it removes filesort, column `filtered` disappeared from explain and processed only 2 rows (don't know how that is possible with LIMIT 15)

Comment: About turning inside out this query - thanks for example. I'll try something with that. I've updated question with tables structure and indexes. But pay attention that SQL generated with Yii2 ActiveRecord and there is some working logic could be lost. Anyway would be appreciate for any ideas to try.

Comment: Please, would you be more concrete with your example "FROM ( SELECT  id, `code`, code_id, last_name..."?